# A hand of six cards is dealt from a standard poker deck. Find formula for p_(XYZ) (x,y,z).

Tags: probability, random-variables

A hand of six cards is dealt from a standard poker deck. Let X denote the number of aces, Y  the number of kings, and Z the number of queens.

a) write a formula for p_(XYZ) (x,y,z).

b) Find  p_(XY)(x,y) .

Solution for a) : A hand of six cards can be selected in 52_C_6 ways.
Since there are 52 cards, there are 4 aces, 4 kings, and 4 queens. 
Let x represent aces, y kings and z queens.
Then X,Y,Z form a hypergeometric distribution. Then x + y + z = 6. then let x denote the number of aces cards selected, since there are 4 , 0 =< x =< 4. Similarly for y and z.
Then p_(XYZ) (x,y,z) = [ 4_C_x * 4_C_y * 4_ C_z]/(52_C_6).

solution for b):
p_(XY)(x,y)  = [ 4_C_x * 4_C_y]/(52_C_6)

Is this right? Can someone please help me? I am not sure. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: x+y+z<=6 because if x=1,y=1,z=1?

Comment: yes the answers seem correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator should be
$$\binom{4}{x}\binom{4}{y}\binom{4}{z}\binom{40}{6-x-y-z},$$
for any $x,y,z$ with $x+y+z\le 6$, with the obvious restrictions on $x,y,z$.

Comment: Where does the 40 come from? Why is it 40_C_(6-x-y-z)?

Comment: can  you clarify please? thank you.

Comment: We are choosing $6$ cards. The number of ways to choose $x$ Aces and so on is what you had written down. But if $x+y+z\lt 6$, we need to choose $6-x-y-z$ cards from the $40$ that are not Ace, King, or Queen to keep the good cards company. As an extreme case, how many hands of $6$ have $x=y=z=0$? Certainly a lot more than the $1$ that $\binom{4}{x}\binom{4}{y}\binom{4}{z}$ would predict.